# Не работает jQuery. В чем может быть проблема?

Tags: jquery, html

Я пытаюсь использовать jQuery, но он не работает.
Вот мой код:

```
<head>
<link type="/public_html" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.map"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="typ">blah blah</div>
</body>
```

script.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#typ").hide();
});
```

Что мне сделать, чтобы все работало?

Comment: а что вы хотите сделать?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/J5TtE/

Answer (score 1):

Вероятнее всего, потому что вы не добавили расширение `.js` в конце названия `jquery-2.1.1.min.map`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<link type="/public_html" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"
```

Во-первых, что за `type="/public_html"`, во-вторых закройте тег link, в-третьих подключайте свой скрипт после определения вашего div-а (на момент выполнения скрипта его еще нет).

Upd Не заметил, что вы ready используете. Тогда третий пункт можно опустить.

Comment: Да, и как подметил @artem328, файл jquery-2.1.1.min.map это не то, что  вам нужно. Подключайте файл именно с разрешением js.

Comment: Спасибо, я сделал как вы сказали, но div всеравно не исчезает. Не видно ли еще ошибок? Public_html - папка, в которой находятся эти файлы.

Answer (score 0):

1) уберите type в link, так как это не путь к стилям. Путь находиться в `href`.
2) Укажите валидную ссылку на скрипт например:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
```

3) Вот пример того что вам нужно, попробуйте и отпишитесь. (путь к стилям прописывать в `href` у `<link>`;

```
 <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
     </script>
 </head>
 <body>
     <div id="typ">blah blah</div>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
 </body>
```